# Forcing polyline to offset from polygon border

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I am currently working on a site with polygons and polylines and am looking for a way to ensure that the polyline does not overlay the site boundary.

I am creating a habitat map and do not want the hedges/ditches which are present on the edge of the site from obscuring the site boundary or vice versa. This only affects some of the polylines, as obviously those in the centre of the site are not affected. Moving the lines manually seems clunky, time-consuming and also wouldn't work at certain zoom levels. Any ideas?

Comment: For the polygons you could buffer the site boundary then do the geoprocessing the cut that area from the features.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work, the hedges/ditches are in a different layer to the site boundary...?

Comment: Vector>Geoprocessing tools>Difference.    https://infogeoblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/geo-processing-in-qgis/